# Opencv Image processing, dilution, intersection, complement

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying out a process from a research that I've read and came across this procedure.
I have tried reading about the processes involved but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

1. Take the binary image `I`
2. Create a marker image `F` which has gray value `255` in
   all pixels except for those pixels along the boundary which are not object pixels in the cell image, where it is `0`.
3. Dilate `F` by `B`, a `5×5` mask that has gray value `0` in all pixels. Let this dilated image be `F ⊕ B`.
4. Take intersection of complement of `I` and `F ⊕ B`. Let this be `H`.
5. Make `F` equal to `H`.
6. Repeat the above steps 3 to 5 for `t` times (experimen-
   tally, t is taken as `1000`).
7. Take intersection of complement of `I` and comple-
   ment of `H`. This gives us the image of holes. Let this
   be `G`.
8. Take union of the `I` and `G` to get the final image,
   which is free of non peripheral holes.

This is the result of their process:

[image]

I wanted to have the same result using this binary image:

[image]

Can someone please explain the thorough process and achieve the same result.

This is where I'm currently at:

```
# LOAD IMAGE
img = cv2.imread('resources/rbc2.png')
# CONVERT TO GRAYSCALE
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgBrightness, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# APPLY MEDIAN BLUR
medianImg = cv2.medianBlur(imgGray,9)

# OTSU THRESHOLDING
ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(medianImg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
complimentI = cv2.bitwise_not(otsu)
```

Comment: All these operations can be implemented via [morphology](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). What are you trying to do? Fill them holes?

Comment: @eldesgraciado yes, I roughly understand theoretically, but I get lost on numbers 2 and 3, do you know how to fill up the holes by implementing this process?

Comment: do you mind if we fill the holes using other methods? This is a fairly simple task in opencv.

Comment: @IanChu yes please, I would be willing to learn them as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is fill holes in a mask, we can do that much more simply by using opencv's findContours. We can filter for small contours and fill in those contours on the mask.

Edit: I am using Opencv 3.4. If you are using Opencv 2.* or 4.* then findContours returns 2 arguments and should look like this:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Filled mask

[image]

```py
import cv2

# load image
gray = cv2.imread("blobs.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

# mask with otsu
_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);

# find contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# filter out contours by size
small_cntrs = [];
for con in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con);
    if area < 1000: # size threshold
        small_cntrs.append(con);
cv2.drawContours(mask, small_cntrs, -1, (0), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```